# Not able to play full animation but in preview its playing fine

Tags: animation

Not able to play full animation but in preview its playing fine

if someone can help me regarding this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by saying '*not able to play full animation, but in preview its playing fine*', but you probably just forgot to add any object to your particle system as a base for these particles. By default, after creating new Particle System Blender will create one with '**Halo**' option as a '**How particles are rendered**' property in the '**Render**' tab in Particle System section in '**Properties**' window:

[image]

Halo particles are apparently not visible when rendered with Cycles Rendering Engine. So, you might either switch to *Blender Render* (not recommended), or preferably just **select some object or Group of objects** to use them as a base for your particles:

[image]

Then, you can customize your Particle System as you wish, with these value highlighted above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know What you are asking For? But pretty Sure you have difficulty with Rendering.

1. Select the Resolution For Final Video.
   [image]

High Resolution will take more Time. 50% saves you 4X time.

2.Select The folder for Output

[image]

3.Choose The format for OutPut

[image]

4.Click Render Animation in Render Menu

[image]

This would Take the Most Time So Grab the Coffee & Relax.

5.To Play Animation Click Play Animation Render Menu

[image]

Comment: first of all thanks for this, i have done all these steps, but when i am playing animation the video is for 0 seconds

Comment: Did you rendered all the frames or aborted in the middle?:

Comment: yes i rendered full